# AngularJS multiple views & controller

Tags: angularjs

I got the following problem in angular and don't really know how to get around it
[image: program layout]

When you click on the modal links a modal windows should open, each modal window should have it's own controller

When clicking on the sidebar I want a the respective sidbar controller to load as well as the linked template url.

I have tried different setups but using normal ng-view all content keeps loading in the sidebar content area.

Any ideas on how to use multiple controllers and views in this manner?

Comment: Though I didn't quite understand your question, I think it might be useful if you have a look at the Angular `ui-router`: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router .

Answer (score 0):

i don't 100% understand your question, but try using ng-include instead of the ng-view. You can use ng-view for the whole page and you can load dynamic partials through controllers. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude